# form should not allowed to submit if all values is 0 if any of from 3 pairs one pair is selected then submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery

below is my jquery code if from 3 pair user click on checkbox and doesn't set min or max level in textbox field then form should not submitted. if any of for example if MinLevelA and MaxLevelA value is selected or it means that if any one pair value is selected then form should be submitted. only validate. [image: image attached for my view]

```
$('#ParLevelSettings').on("click", ".Savebtn", function (event) {  //on click
    var isValid = true;

    $('#ParLevelSettings input.isincludechk:checked, #ParLevelSettings input.ischanged[value="true"]').closest('div.row-fluid').find('.minlvl').each(function () {
        var min = $(this).get(0);
        var max = $(this).closest('div').next('div').find('.maxlvl').get(0)
        var dataVal = $(this).data("ichange");
        var minval = parseInt(min.value);
        var maxval = parseInt(max.value);

        if(minval != 0 && maxval != 0)
        {   
            var isSet = $("#isSet_" + dataVal);
            isSet.val(true);
            return;
        }
            if (isNaN(minval) || minval > maxval) {
                $(min).css({
                    "border": "1px solid red",
                    "background": "#FFCECE"
                });
                $(min).attr('title', 'Min level should not be empty or Min level should be less than the Max level or must give some value to min level');
                isValid = false;
            }
        else {
            $(min).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
        if (isNaN(maxval) || maxval < minval) {
            $(max).css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });

            $(max).attr('title', 'Max level should not be empty or Max level should be greater than the Min level or must give some value to min level');
            isValid = false;
        }
        else {
            $(max).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
    });

    if (isValid == false) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: So it shouldn't submit if ANY value is 0?

Comment: if all value is 0 then it should not submitted if user give any MINLevelA or MaxLevelB value then form should be submitted

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#formID").on("submit", function(){
//use the condition in your example
     if(condition==true){
          return true;
     }
     else{
          //display some reason why the form was not submitted.
          return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: I've to submit the form against the value set. if checkbox is checked and user give value any two textboxes in one row...

Comment: Are you trying to POST the changes for each row using ajax?